# databinding and focus coordination

Tags: wpf, data-binding, focus

I have several controls including a DataGrid that I want to be disabled until there is a valid value in the first TextBox in the presentation. So I added a boolean property to bind to in the VM and bind to it in the xaml (below).

The binding works, but has the side effect of 'trapping' the user in the TextBox (MoneyToAllocate).

Presumably this is because the TB binding is LostFocus and there is no place for the focus to go and actually trigger the updates. What's a good way to fix this?

Cheers,
Berryl

## ViewModel

```
public bool HasMoneyToAllocate { get { return MoneyToAllocate.Amount > 0; } }

public Money MoneyToAllocate {
    get { return _moneyToAllocate; }
    set {
        if (value.Amount < 0) return;

        _moneyToAllocate = new Money(value.Amount, SelectedCurrency);
        NotifyPropertyChanged(() => HasMoneyToAllocate);
    }
}
```

## View

```
    <TextBox Text="{Binding MoneyToAllocate, Converter={StaticResource moneyConverter}}"  />

    <DataGrid IsEnabled="{Binding HasMoneyToAllocate}" ...
```

## EDIT

I should have added that I tried PropertyChanged for update but it gets a bit messy since the value of the text box needs to be formatted by the converter. Any other ideas?

## FINAL EDIT

I wound up letting another control that previously wasn't a tab stop be a tab stop, so the text box had a place to go. Phil understood the problem best and gets the answer, even though the range of values the user can input (.001 to decimal.MaxValue) make an up-down impractical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`

```
<TextBox 
    Text="{Binding MoneyToAllocate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
           Converter={StaticResource moneyConverter}}"  />
```

Comment: What about using a DecimalUpDown control, such as from the extended WPF toolkit?  Force there to always be a valid number in the control and enable the rest of the UI when it's > 0.

Answer (score 1):

Then you have to use UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged 
- if you use that binding you are using the value in the VM will not effected till the focus moves from the textBox 
- but if you add UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged to your binding the VM property (MoneyToAllocate) will effected immediately (when the textBox.Text value changed)